# Find a length 100 cycle in an undirected graph is NP Complete?

Tags: np-complete

Given a graph G with N nodes we need to find if cycle of length 100 exists.

I've been told that this problem is NP-Complete and can be reduced to the Hamiltonian Cycle problem. I believe this is just P.

My first thought was just to perform a DFS on each node with a max depth of 101 nodes and check if the last node equals the first. Given a starting node you have at most (n-1) nodes connected to it we need to search. That node has at most(n-2) nodes connected to it we need to search. Thus for each starting node we have a time complexity of O(n^101). Multiply by the number of nodes we need to do this over and we have O(n^102).

Am I correct or did I get something wrong here?

Comment: As you mention, this is in P. If the length of the cycle is not 100 but a part of the input, then it is np complete.